# Как можно передать в C++ температуру процессора?

Tags: c++

Я хочу написать простенькую программку, которая будет мониторить температуру процессора какое-то время и выводить мне. Я ограничу массив и буду выводить, пока не дойду до границы массива. Меня интересует, как именно подать компилятору эти данные.

Comment: ось то какая? Если под линуком, то там есть lm_sensors.

Comment: Винда семерка

Comment: пробуйте wmi. Но нужно, что бы драйвера были правильно установлены. гуглите на тему "wmi cpu".

Answer (score 2):

Опять же - стандартных библиотек не существует для решения этой задачи. Необходимо искать конкретную библиотеку, которая имеет биндинг к С++, и использовать ее. Можно воспользоваться интерфейсом WMI (один из относительно стандартных API ОС Windows), через который считать показания из ACPI Thermal Zone. Пример можно посмотреть на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327203/how-to-access-cpus-heat-sensors)